symlink-install with easy_install python warning
I have encountered an issue when I try to use --symlink-install when I try to build my packages with colcon.
This is my scenario:

When I colcon build my workspace, I have no issue
When I colcon build a specific package, I have no issue
When I colcon build a specific package with --symlink-install, then I have an issue which I don't understand, with easy_install being deprecated
When I return to use colcon build with a specific package, now I get an error for easy_install.

I am using setuptools version 69.2.0
Can someone please explain why I get the this error and how I should fix it? and why it now makes me have an error when I try to colcon build without symlink-install?
    user@user:~/ros2_ws$ colcon build
    Starting >>> my_cpp_pkg
    Starting >>> my_py_pkg
    Finished <<< my_cpp_pkg [0.48s]                                                    
    Finished <<< my_py_pkg [1.24s]          

    Summary: 2 packages finished [1.37s]
    user@user:~/ros2_ws$ colcon build --packages-select my_py_pkg 
    Starting >>> my_py_pkg
    Finished <<< my_py_pkg [1.27s]          

    Summary: 1 package finished [1.40s]
    user@user:~/ros2_ws$ colcon build --packages-select my_py_pkg --symlink-install
    Starting >>> my_py_pkg
    --- stderr: my_py_pkg                   
    /home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py:40: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated.
    !!

            ********************************************************************************
            Please avoid running ``setup.py`` and ``easy_install``.
            Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
            standards-based tools.

            See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/917 for details.
            ********************************************************************************

    !!
      easy_install.initialize_options(self)
    ---
    Finished <<< my_py_pkg [1.42s]

    Summary: 1 package finished [1.55s]
      1 package had stderr output: my_py_pkg
    user@user:~/ros2_ws$ colcon build --packages-select my_py_pkg 
    Starting >>> my_py_pkg
    --- stderr: my_py_pkg                   
    /home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py:40: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated.
    !!

            ********************************************************************************
            Please avoid running ``setup.py`` and ``easy_install``.
            Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
            standards-based tools.

            See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/917 for details.
            ********************************************************************************

    !!
      easy_install.initialize_options(self)
    ---
    Finished <<< my_py_pkg [1.79s]

    Summary: 1 package finished [1.92s]
      1 package had stderr output: my_py_pkg
    user@user:~/ros2_ws$ pip3 list | grep setuptools
    setuptools                           69.2.0

